# NameError: name 'x' is not defined & display results in GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm getting this error. Also, I'm trying to get x which is the result to be displayed in the entrybox but I keep getting errors. [windowimage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4DfA.png)

1. User enter the information and click on submit button
2. It will retrieve the results from excel and display it in in the entrybox below.
3. All the information (e.g. customers, parts ID, device ID) will be displayed

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd
from Datamine import *


#create window
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("JCET Search System")
window.geometry("500x500")


def datamine():
# read excel files
    df = pd.read_excel ('N:/TEST/TEST UTILIZATION/IA 2020/Dev/SCS-FT-IE-Report.xlsm', sheet_name= 'FT')
    df2 = pd.read_excel ('N:/TEST/TEST UTILIZATION/IA 2020/Dev/HW_STATUS_TOTAL_FEB28.xlsx', sheet_name= 'HW_STATUS_TOTAL_FEB28')
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ["MFG Device", "LOADBOARDGRPNAME","SOCKETGRPNAME", "PRIHANDLERFULLKIT"])
    df1.set_index("MFG Device")
    i=0
#store user input into value
    greeting = entrymc.get()
#search results containing value
    x = df1[df1['MFG Device'].str.contains(greeting)]
#display search results (in shell)
    print(x)
    return(x) 

#function for command
#def callback2():
   # name = "You entered: ",entrymc.get()
    
    #return name 

#display text
def phrase_display(x):
    
    textbox1.delete("1.0", "end")
    textbox1.insert(tk.END, str(x))
    textbox1.pack(x)
    
    
# to have more than 2 commands in a button    
#def combine_funcs(*funcs):
    #def combined_func(*args, **kwargs):
        #for f in funcs:
            #f(*args, **kwargs)
    #return combined_func

#label
labelmc = tk.Label(text="Enter Parts ID #", fg= "black")
labelmc.grid(column=1, row=2)

label5 = tk.Label(text="Results", fg= "black")
label5.grid(column=1, row=7)

#entry field
entrymc = tk.Entry(width = 30)
entrymc.grid(column=2, row=2)

#button
button1 = tk.Button(text="Submit", command= lambda:[phrase_display(x),datamine()])
button1.grid(column=4, row=2)

#text box
textbox1 = tk.Text(master=window, height=15, width =50, bg="white")
textbox1.grid(column=1,row=10, columnspan=7, rowspan =500)


window.mainloop()
```

Shell:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sgtiocqn\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\sgtiocqn\Desktop\gui.py", line 62, in <lambda>
    button1 = tk.Button(text="Submit", command= lambda:[phrase_display(x),datamine()])
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sgtiocqn\Desktop\gui.py", line 5, in <module>
    from Datamine import *
  File "C:\Users\sgtiocqn\Desktop\Datamine.py", line 19, in <module>
    greeting = entrymc.get()
  File "C:\Users\sgtiocqn\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2682, in get
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'get')
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!entry"
```

Comment: Why do you ask agin, you already got a answer here: [typeerror-phrase-display-missing-1-required-positional-argument-x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62506041)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just worken up so need to let the coffee set in BUT

Looks like first you need to call

```
x = datamine()
```

to get the x variable

OR do this (i.e feed the datamine function INTO phrase_display)

```
button1 = tk.Button(text="Submit", command= lambda:[phrase_display(datamine())])
```

phrase_display is expecting the x varible, and you are passing an x in.

But if you checked, x is not initialised at that point.